# Moment js time stamp format should be 00 instead of 24

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

Here is the example:

```
const date = "2/26/2021 12:33:14 AM";

const result = moment(date, 'M/D/YYYY hh:mm:ss a').format('YYYYMMDDkkmmss');

console.log(result); // output: 20210226243314
```

The output result is "20210226**24**3314", But my expected result "20210226**00**3314".

How can I change the once reached 12AM the output should be 00 instead of 24.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `kk` when you want `HH` -> https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: I tried but when I use `HH` instead of `kk`, it will not be considered the `AM` and `PM`

Comment: `moment("2/26/2021 12:33:14 AM", 'M/D/YYYY hh:mm:ss a').format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss'); // -> "20210226003314"` works as expected. If this is not the case for you then add a [mcve]